# UPDATE sql Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: java, sql

I have an application that I am working on that will query a database and display the results. The program also makes changes to the database (update, delete, insert). I had most of these features working correctly until recently when I made some changes. Now I am getting an SQLException that tells me I am violating a foreign key constraint. I have looked it up and found out that the violation is a result of more than one table sharing data. Is there a way to overcome this? How would I make the update without violating the constraint? here is my update method:

```
InstructorEditorPanel updateEditorPanel = new InstructorEditorPanel();

updateEditorPanel.setFieldText(InstructorEditorPanel.FieldTitle.B_NUMBER, updBNumber);
updateEditorPanel.setFieldText(InstructorEditorPanel.FieldTitle.FIRST_NAME, updFName);
updateEditorPanel.setFieldText(InstructorEditorPanel.FieldTitle.LAST_NAME, updLName);


int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, updateEditorPanel,
              "Update Instructor",        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
  if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
  {
      for (InstructorEditorPanel.FieldTitle fieldTitle :    InstructorEditorPanel.FieldTitle
                 .values()) {

                    bNum =    getBNumber(updateEditorPanel.getFieldText(fieldTitle.values()[0]));
                    fName = getFirstName(updateEditorPanel.getFieldText(fieldTitle.values()[1]));
                    lName =  getLastName(updateEditorPanel.getFieldText(fieldTitle.values()[2]));
                   }
      try
{
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    updateInstructor = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE Instructor SET BNUMBER = ?, FIRSTNAME = ?, LASTNAME = ? WHERE BNUMBER = ?");

}catch(SQLException sqlException){
    sqlException.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}//end catch
  try
{

    updateInstructor.setString(1, bNum);
    updateInstructor.setString(2, fName);
    updateInstructor.setString(3, lName);
            updateInstructor.setString(4,mNumber);

    updateInstructor.executeUpdate();
}catch(SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
}//end of catch
finally
{
    close();
}//end 
  }


Display(panel); }
```

I had the method working without any problems until recently when I made some changes. I don't know what I did, but now I am getting the foreign key constraint violated exception

here is the exception:java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: UPDATE on table 'INSTRUCTOR' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'SQL120408141918440' for key (1234500000).  The statement has been rolled back.

database info

```
CREATE TABLE Instructor (
BNumber varchar(10) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(20),
LastName varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (BNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Section (
CRN int NOT NULL,
Term varchar(6) NOT NULL,
SectionNumber varchar(3),
CourseID varchar(9),
Enrollment smallint,
BNumber varchar(10),
PercentResp numeric(5,2),
CONSTRAINT CRN_Term PRIMARY KEY (CRN,Term),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES Course (CourseID), 
FOREIGN KEY (BNumber) REFERENCES Instructor (BNumber)
);

INSERT INTO Instructor (BNumber, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES 
('0000012345','Bill','Smith'),
('0000023456','Sue','Taylor'),
('0000034567','Skilar','Ramsey'),
('1234500000','Sam','Jones'),
('2345600000','Tyson','Quilez');

INSERT INTO Section (CRN, Term, SectionNumber, CourseID, Enrollment,
                 BNumber, PercentResp)
VALUES 
(40035,'201040','02B','CHM2210', 31,'0000034567',100),
(40001,'201040','02B','CGS1000', 27,'0000012345',100),
(40002,'201040','70B','CGS2100', 25,'0000012345',100),
(40003,'201040','71B','CGS2100', 19,'0000012345',100),
(40004,'201040','01B','COP1000', 15,'0000012345',100),
(40030,'201040','01B','BSCC1005',30,'0000023456',100),
(40031,'201040','02B','BSCC1005',25,'0000023456',100),
(40032,'201040','70B','BSCC1005',24,'0000023456',100),
(40000,'201040','01B','CGS1000', 15,'0000012345',100),
(40034,'201040','01B','CHM2210', 27,'0000034567',100);
```

Comment: Can you post details of what tables the instructor table is related to via foreign keys, and on which fields?

Comment: yes I will update the question

Comment: I tried updating the Sections BNumber before updating the Instructor BNumber but it was still giving me the Exception

Comment: are you trying to set the Bnumber for an instructor who is being referenced by sections? In this case sql wont allow update since if you change bnumber from 2 to 10, then the foreign key 2 will have no meaning in the database even though sections will be poining to it? Solution use cascading update or delete the relation.. better still dont allow the manual setting of bnumber and use a sequence to automatically generate bnumber for the instructors

Comment: could you please tell what exact values you updated?

Comment: In the instructor table I am trying to change the BNumber 0000012345 First Name Bill Last Name Smith to 0000012346 Shane Kelsey. I have never used a cascading update before. I have to allow the manual setting of BNumber, as it's a part of the application features

Comment: so what did you do to the sections assigned to bill before making this change?

Comment: cascading update forces the change into the linked tables.. I havent used it myself personally.. but i know it exists in sql

Comment: I tried to change the Bnumber in the Sections table then do the same in the instructor table. I think what I want to do is the cascading update. my attempt to change the BNumber in section didn't work, I got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
"UPDATE Instructor SET BNUMBER = ?, FIRSTNAME = ?, LASTNAME = ? WHERE BNUMBER = ?"
```

With

```
"UPDATE Instructor SET FIRSTNAME = ?, LASTNAME = ? WHERE BNUMBER = ?"
```

You should not update the primary key if it's the matching condition in your update query.

Comment: okay, so from what I understand the primary key is never changed? I wouldn't be able to change the Bnumber in the instructor table and have all other Bnumbers in the sections table change with the update?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. if you want the change the bnumber in the referencing tables where it's declared as foreign key, you can do so (in your case to reaffect i guess the courses to a different instructor). but if you have a new instructor, you should create a new entry with a new bnumber.

Answer (score 0):

You should put ON UPDATE CASCADE after the references